# Extracting continuous colour information (saturation, contrast, etc) from video mp4 files in R

Tags: r, video, time-series, mp4, analysis

I would like to analyse some videos I have to extract frame-by-frame or second-by-second information about colour, saturation, and contrast.

I've never done this before and am simply unable to find any information on the internet about this. I have seen a few analyses of static images, but nothing about video.

Fore reproducibility, here is a randomly generated video from the `av::` package:

```
video <- av::av_demo()
```

I would like to extract information in a time-series fashion. For example:
What are the average R/G/B values or other colour information at each second?
Saturation values?
Contrast values?

Ideally, the analysis would provide a data frame where each row is one second and each column is a variable. The values at each second could average over multiple frames.

Videos I have in real life range from 1 minute to about 4.5 minutes.

I appreciate that there may be a different way to describe the values I am looking for and am open to options and suggestions.

Comment: You're not telling others where you're stuck... You need to extract images of each frame and analyze the R/G/B and saturation values. **(1)** Are you able to play a video in R? Can you seek frame-by-frame? Can you get each frame as a bitmap (of pixels) to analyse the R/G/B values.... If not, then maybe R is the wrong tool for this task... **(2)** If you simply want a fast result then I would recommend using Javascript as an analysis tool since it's already in your web browser. Chrome is the most capable browser (for JS features).

Comment: PS: Another option... See if FFmpeg can be run from R and also if it can be run as a **process** (meaning it uses standard input/output, also called **std io**). Use FFmpeg to decode the video into RGB data (array) and save each frame (array) as a file to analyze bytes for RGB, or else avoid file saving by reading data/array back into R using standard i/o API...